# Configure Fiddler to capture .Net Service

Tags: .net, windows-services, fiddler

I have a .Net service which creates a HttpWebRequest.  I'd like to see these by using Fiddler.

I've done a bit of searching and the general suggestion is to add a proxy into the machine.config file.

```
<!-- The following section is to force use of Fiddler for all applications, 
Including those running in service accounts -->  <system.net>
<defaultProxy>
<proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" 
proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
</defaultProxy>
```

Having done this I still see nothing.

The only difference I have is that within my code I need to specify another proxy

```
const string myProxyHostString = "10.10.10.2";
const int myProxyPort = 8080;
httpWebRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(myProxyHostString, myProxyPort);
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

The proxy you configure in code overwrites the configuration that lets your requests flow through Fiddler.

Do you really need to specify this proxy from code? Otherwise you could put it in your `app.config`, and point it at Fiddler when debugging and at `10.10.10.2` when running in production.

Then in Fiddler, [configure `10.10.10.2` as upstream proxy](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ChainToUpstreamProxy).

This way your requests will flow like this:

```
Application -> Fiddler -> 10.10.10.2 -> destination
```